# Save Datepicker Date to Database

Tags: android, sqlite, datepicker

after 3 days of searching for a solution I hope someone can help me here,  I'm a new to android development and I'm trying to save the date of my datepicker dialog or my datepicker widget to my sqlite database, I get no errors but it's saving my date as 12/31/1969 no matter what I do this is my DatePickerFragment Class

```
    public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    private Calendar dateTime = Calendar.getInstance();


    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Using current date as start Date
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Get DatePicker Dialog
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }


    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

        TextView chooseDateLabel = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.chooseDateLabel);

        dateTime.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);

        final int myYear = year;
        final int myMonth = monthOfYear;
        final int myDay = dayOfMonth;

        chooseDateLabel.setText(new StringBuilder().append(myMonth + 1).append("/").append(myDay)
                .append("/").append(myYear).append(" "));
        DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.saveJobDatePicker);

        datePicker.init(myYear, myMonth, myDay, new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                year = myYear;
                monthOfYear = myMonth;
                dayOfMonth = myDay;

                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put("productDate", year + monthOfYear + dayOfMonth);


            }
        });


        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("date", myDay + myMonth + myYear);

    }
}
```

as you can see I have a textview that display the choosen date no problem.
this is my DataBaseHelper code that adds to table.

```
     //add content to table
    public void addProduct(MyProduct product){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(PRODUCT_NAME, product.getproductName());
    values.put(PRODUCT_NUMBER, product.getproductNumber());
    values.put(PRODUCT_WEIGHT, product.getproductWeight());
    values.put(PRODUCT_QTY, product.getproductQTY());
    values.put(DATE_NAME, product.getproductDate());

    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);


    Log.v("Wish successfully!", "yeah!!");

    db.close();
}
```

and this is how I'm attempting to save the date.

```
    private void saveProductDB() {


    Intent intent = getIntent();
    final Double myLabelResults = intent.getDoubleExtra("totalQTY", 0.0);

    final MyProduct product = new MyProduct();
    product.setproductName(saveproductNameText.getText().toString().trim());
    product.setproductNumber(Integer.valueOf(saveproductNumberText.getText().toString().trim()));
    product.setproductWeight(myLabelResults);
    product.setproductQTY(myLabelResults / 14);
    product.getproductPavingOnLabel();

    saveProductDate = (DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.saveProductDatePicker);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    int day = saveProductDate.getDayOfMonth();
    int month = saveProductDate.getMonth();
    int year = saveProductDate.getYear();

    calendar.set(day, month, year);
    long myLongDate = calendar.getTimeInMillis();


    product.setProductDate(myLongDate);

    dba.Product(product);
    dba.close();

    saveproductNameText.setText("");
    saveproductNumberText.setText("");

    Intent i = new Intent(SaveProduct.this, MyProductActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Product Saved",      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

my database table is generated like this

```
  @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    //create our table

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME+ "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, PRODUCTNAME TEXT, PRODUCTNUMBER INTEGER, PRODUCTQTY REAL, PRODUCTWEIGHT REAL, PRODUCTDATE LONG, PRODUCTCOMPLETED INTEGER)");

}
```

inside my getView method I'am attempting to format my long to string like this

```
 long dateFromProductDate = holder.myProduct.getProductDate();
 String dateString = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(new Date(dateFromProductDate));
 holder.mJobsDate.setText(dateString);
```

can somebody help me figure out where am I making the mistake thanks.

Comment: " it's saving my date as 12/31/1969 no matter what I do " - how do you want to save your date?

Comment: Sorry what I meant is that is not saving the date from datepicker and its defaulting to 12/31/1969 and ignoring the selected date on datepicker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem, thanks a lot @Nolly j for the help, inside my product activity I have a refreshData method that had the date setup as a string for testing purposes and forgot to change it to long, here it is.

```
  private void refreshData() {
    dbProducts.clear();
    dba = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

    ArrayList<MyProduct> productsFromDB = dba.getProducts();

    for (int i = 0; i < productsFromDB.size(); i++){

        String productName = productsFromDB.get(i).getProductName();
        int  productNumber = productsFromDB.get(i).getProductNumber();
        Double productTons = productsFromDB.get(i).getProductWeight();
        Double productTrucks = productsFromDB.get(i).getProductQTY();
        //String productDate = productsFromDB.get(i).getProductBirthDate();
        long productDate = productsFromDB.get(i).getProductDate();

        MyProduct myProduct = new MyProduct();
        myProduct.setProductName(productName);
        myProduct.setProductNumber(productNumber);
        myProduct.setProductTons(productWeight);
        myProduct.setProductTrucks(productQTY);
        myProduct.setProductDate(productDate);
        //myJob.setProductDate(ProductDate);

        dbProducts.add(myProduct);
    }
```

the commented out statements were the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a simple code that will put you in right direction. The selected datetime is global and it is accessible.

```
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static TextView chooseDateLabel;

private DatePickerFragment datePickerFragment;
private static Calendar dateTime = Calendar.getInstance();

protected static int mYear;
protected static int mMonth;
protected static int mDay;

private static long dateInMilliSeconds;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    chooseDateLabel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.chooseDateLabel);

    datePickerFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    datePickerFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "My Date Picker");

}

public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Using current date as start Date
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Get DatePicker Dialog
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

        mYear = year;
        mMonth = monthOfYear;
        mDay = dayOfMonth;

        chooseDateLabel.setText(String.valueOf(mDay) + "/" + String.valueOf(mMonth) + "/" + String.valueOf(mYear));

        dateTime.set(mYear, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
        dateInMilliSeconds = dateTime.getTimeInMillis();
    }
}

private void saveProductDB(){

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    final Double myLabelResults = intent.getDoubleExtra("totalQTY", 0.0);

    final MyProduct product = new MyProduct();
    product.setproductName(saveproductNameText.getText().toString().trim());
    product.setproductNumber(Integer.valueOf(saveproductNumberText.getText().toString().trim()));
    product.setproductWeight(myLabelResults);
    product.setproductQTY(myLabelResults / 14);
    product.setProductDate(dateInMilliSeconds);
    product.getproductPavingOnLabel();

    dba.Product(product);
    dba.close();

    saveproductNameText.setText("");
    saveproductNumberText.setText("");

    Intent i = new Intent(SaveProduct.this, MyProductActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
}
```

this is the getView code for my list view

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView;
        //ViewHolder holder = null;

        if(row == null || (row.getTag()) == null){

            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResorce, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.mProductName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.ProductNameLabel);
            holder.mProductNumber = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.ProductNumberLabel);
            holder.mProductWeight = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.WeightLabel);
            holder.mProductQTY = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.QTYLable);
            holder.mProductDate = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.dateLabel);                

            row.setTag(holder);
        }else{

            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        holder.myProduct = getItem(position);

        holder.mProductName.setText(holder.myProduct.getProductName());
        holder.mProductNumber.setText(String.valueOf(holder.myProduct.getProductNumber()));
        holder.mProductWeight.setText(String.format("%.1f", holder.myProduct.getProductWeight()) + " Weight");
        holder.mProductQTY.setText(String.format("%.1f", holder.myProduct.getProductQTY()) + " QTY");

        long dateFromProductDate = holder.myProduct.getProductDate();
        String dateString = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(new Date(dateFromProductDate));
        holder.mProductDate.setText(dateString);

        return row;
    } 

   //get all products
public ArrayList<MyProduct> getProducts(){

    //String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[]{ PRODUCT_NAME, PRODUCT_NUMBER, PRODUCT_QTY,
            PRODUCT_WEIGHT, DATE_NAME}, null, null, null, null, "PRODUCTDATE DESC");

    //loop through cursor
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{

            MyProduct job = new MyProduct();
            product.setProductName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PRODUCT_NAME)));
            product.setProductNumber(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(PRODUCT_NUMBER)));
            product.setProductWeight(cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(PRODUCT_WEIGHT)));
            product.setProductQTY(cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(PRODUCT_QTY)));
            //product.setProductDate(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(DATE_NAME)));

            long milliSeconds = product.setProductDate(cursor.getLong(product.getProductDate()));
            DateFormat df = new SimpleFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
            String dateString = df.format(new Date(milliSeconds)).toString();

            //java.text.DateFormat dateFormat = java.text.DateFormat.getDateInstance();
            //String dateData = dateFormat.format(new Date(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(DATE_NAME))).getTime());
            product.setProductDate(dateString);

            productList.add(product);

        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    return productList;
}
```

Comment: well it seems I'm getting a value, dateInMilliSeconds now = 1473136589551 Thanks, but still my listview is displaying 12/31/1969, I'll post my getView code.

Comment: You need to insert this value to your database, When you retrieve it from database you will format it to the date format you need.

Comment: The values are in the database, to make sure I exported the database and found all the dates there just can't figure out how to format and display on my listview I've tried DateFormat but I still can't.

Comment: After you have inserted the date as long type in your database, try and try the value and see if it is same before I set it to your List item? If it is the same, your can do it this way. long longInMilliSecond = // from database; String dateInString= DateFormat.format("MM/dd/yyyy", new Date(longInMilliSecond)).toString();

Comment: still no good, somehow my date textview is getting the value of 12/31/1969, I'll post the code of my databaseHelper getProducts(), hopefully the bug is in there and I can't spot it.